# Armadillo Does not Find BLAS Linear Algebra Package

Tags: armadillo

I have cross-compiled Armadillo for ARMv7 using my Red Hat.

When I try to do matrix multiplication I get the error:

```
armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:79: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
```

I built BLAS and LAPACK from source, it seems to find LAPACK as it lets me do Cholesky decomposition without errors.

I have built like this:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -march=armv7-a     -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard  
-mfpu=neon    
-mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/mg/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/socfpga_cyclone5  
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   --sysroot=/home/mg/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots 
/socfpga_cyclone5  -g -O2 -L/opt/altera-linux/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf- 
4.7-2012.11-20121123_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -I/opt/altera-linux/linaro 
/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2012.11-20121123_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf 
/include  -llapack -lf2c  -lblas -lm --sysroot=/home/mg/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots 
/socfpga_cyclone5 -MT AlgoLibTests.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/AlgoLibTests.Tpo -c -o  
AlgoLibTests.o AlgoLibTests.cpp
```

I put my BLAS and LAPACK here:

```
/opt/altera-linux/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf- 
4.7-2012.11-20121123_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib
```

If I disable that BLAS support, it does the calculations very slowly.

This is defined in the config file

```
ARMA_USE_BLAS
```

And this is disabled.

```
ARMA_USE_WRAPPER
```

ATLAS is also disabled.  Why does it not find that BLAS library?

Comment: If any function starting with `wrapper_` is being used, it means that ARMA_USE_WRAPPER is still enabled. Check whether you have multiple copies of Armadillo installed (eg. in /usr/include or /usr/local/include or somewhere in your home dir)

Comment: Hello mtall, I do have two installed one on my Red Hat and the other from source for ARM.  In the link.txt file, I took away all of the links to the use/include etc..   Also that Cholesky decomposition takes 70ms to execute on a 241x241 matrix.  Do you know why it is so slow?  Is that normal?

Comment: That should be Cholesky + inv(r)*inv(r.t())*B takes 70ms, my own made code takes 40ms.  I thought BLAS would be quicker.  Using Solve(X,A,B) takes 250ms??

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error too when I tried to compile Armadillo for my Android project. I am sure that ARMA_USE_WRAPPER is not yet disabled. That is why you get the error *undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'*. Check it again.

I also notice that the matrix computation on Mobile is way slower than that in my Mac OS.